# two point correlation of point process

Tags: pr.probability

I got very confused by the 'real meaning' of the two point correlation of the point process, especially in random matrix theory, say, 
$$K_n(x,y)=\mathbb E(\sum \delta(x)\otimes \sum \delta(y))$$
then people rescale it, say by a factor of $n^{-1/2}$ and show 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} K_n(p+\frac x{n^{\frac 12}},p+\frac y{n^{\frac 12}}) =K_\infty(x,y)$$ 
what does this limit means? Does it mean that the average order of the distance between all points is $n^{-1/2}$? People also say, if
$K_\infty(x,y)\to 0$ when $x\to y$, then the process behaves 'repulsion', what does this mean?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MO. I suggest you do some serious editting to this question, as most of your notations are without any definitions, and therefore your post is very hard to dechiphre. Good Luck

Comment: rescaling just makes sure that the average separation of the points remains fixed when you increase $n$. So if the average separation scales as $n^{-1/2}$, dividing by that scale ensures the rescaled average separation is fixed at unity. And then repulsion just means that the probability to find two neighboring points at separation much less than their average separation vanishes, with some power of the separation.